# dos batch rename folders (another one)

Tags: windows, batch

no way to find what i try (so simple):
i have this structure:

+folder1 (contains:)

```
   -folder2
   -folder3
   -...
   -folderi
```

I just want to add simple word (WORD) after the folders 2...i
simple ?
I shoul get:

```
 -folder1WORD
 -folder2WORD
 -...
 -folderiWORD
```

BUT i dont want to change folder1 name (i have succeed only to change ALL the folders)

BUT some of them have space in their name ( i have succeed to transform "folder with space" in 3 other ones folderWORD and withWORD and spaceWORD.

BUT should be a SPACE as first caracter of WORD (no way to make this)

right now i have try with what i found in the other threads without success !!!

Anyone get a way to do this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry i cannot add hello to all in the fist line (edit not recorded ?)

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, then this will work for an interactive command prompt:

```
for /d %D IN (c:\temp\folder1\*.*) do ren "%D" "%~nxDWORD"
```

If you are running this inside a batch file, then you will need to double each of the percent signs:

```
for /d %%D IN (c:\temp\folder1\*.*) do ren "%%D" "%%~nxDWORD"
```

The `/d` option tells `for` to only look at directories.  The `~nxD` modifier tells it to only print the file**n**ame and e**x**tension of `D` rather than the full path.  See `FOR /?` for more information on the syntax of the modifiers.

## Example:

### Before

```
c:\temp\folder1>dir c:\temp\folder1

 Directory of c:\temp\folder1

<DIR>          folder with space
<DIR>          folder.dotted
<DIR>          folder2
<DIR>          folder3
<DIR>          folderi
```

### Command

```
c:\temp\folder1>for /d %D IN (c:\temp\folder1\*.*) do ren "%D" "%~nxDWORD"

c:\temp\folder1>ren "c:\temp\folder1\folder with space" "folder with spaceWORD"
c:\temp\folder1>ren "c:\temp\folder1\folder.dotted" "folder.dottedWORD"
c:\temp\folder1>ren "c:\temp\folder1\folder2" "folder2WORD"
c:\temp\folder1>ren "c:\temp\folder1\folder3" "folder3WORD"
c:\temp\folder1>ren "c:\temp\folder1\folderi" "folderiWORD"
```

### Results

```
c:\temp\folder1>dir

 Directory of c:\temp\folder1

<DIR>          folder with spaceWORD
<DIR>          folder.dottedWORD
<DIR>          folder2WORD
<DIR>          folder3WORD
<DIR>          folderiWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

@ GuitarPicker

thank for your answer, but not working here.

1 yes it is a batch file (part of another one)

2 for real usage the bat file is in the first folder 
so i modify your code as this: it works on the parent folder but, not in the childs

```
:: for testing
echo %e%*.*
pause
dir %e%*.*
pause

for /d %%D IN (%e%*.*) do ren "%%D" "%%~nxDWORD"
pause
```

@ DavidPostill

my starting code looks like:

```
 echo off
 for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/ad') do (
 echo %%a
 ::this works made new folder with extension even with space
 mkdir "%%a"_WORD_test
 ::this does not work
 ren %%a "%%a"_WORD
)
 pause
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

found a way but without complete success : I have this:

get list of the sub folders :OK

does not treat the parent folder: OK

get the good name to rename:OK

BUT rename itself does NOT work...

```
@echo off
Set /a COUNTER=0
 setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 :: affiche les dossiers en inverse MAIS aussi le dossier parent NO USE
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (`dir /ad /b /s /o-n`) do (
  ::on saute le premier - skip first =  parent dir
  echo testing %%a
  echo counter !counter!
  if !counter!==0 (
  echo abstention
  ) ELSE (
   echo Renaming %%a in %%a_pdf
  ::echo en %%a_pdf
  ::ren "%%a" "%%a"_pdf
   )
  set /a COUNTER=COUNTER+1
  )

  endlocal
  pause
```

I get this in CMD window (note there are errors without rename command active (i mean when rename is in remarks as in the script before):

```
testing M:\x_bd\test\test_inside
counter 0
abstention
testing M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mayam_01-02
counter 1
Renaming M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mayam_01-02 in M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mayam_01-02_pdf
Le lecteur spécifié est introuvable.
testing M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mac
counter 2
Renaming M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mac in M:\x_bd\test\test_inside\Mac_pdf
Le lecteur spécifié est introuvable.
...
```

Mysteries of DOS ?
If anyone can help...